# GetFoldersAsync sorted not by name but by last modified?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to display a list of recently modified items, sorted by date. They are contained in folders as there are multiple types of information I need to store for each item. All items are stored in the localfolder.

One way would be to rename the folders by their date when the item is modified, but this could create collisions if two items are modified at the same time. Is there a way to sort the folders by the last modified time that Explorer shows?

Comment: Sort by date before displaying to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DirectoryInfo` objects `GetDirectories()` method returns an array of `DirectoryInfo` objects with the various dates populated -- including `LastWriteTime`.

Just sort by the appropriate property and do what you want with the result.

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getdirectories?view=netframework-4.7.1

If you are wanting the last modified date for the individual files within a folder, `GetFiles()' method returns the an array of`FileInfo` objects, again with various date properties populated.

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.1

As an alternative, if the number of files/folders is large or has to be read frequently, it may be better to keep a text files in each folder and update it with each change to contain a summary of the current state of the files in that folder.